# Is there such a thing as private resources within AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know of private and public subnets, but have never heard of the term 'private resources' before. I've been asked that whenever I make resources, to make them private, so I'm doing my due diligence in trying to understand what that exactly means.

Does it mean to simply leave the `Publicly accessible` box/option unchecked when spinning up an EC2 instance, Redshift cluster, or any other resource? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: Only RDS/Redshift have Publicly Accessible flags. How you make something "private" on AWS depends on what specific AWS service you are using. The answer for an S3 bucket is going to be different from the answer for an EC2 server, which is going to be different from an API Gateway, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The term **private resource** is not used by AWS.

Typically, **making something private** refers to the practice of putting resources in a **Private Subnet**, which means it is not directly accessible from the Internet.

An Amazon EC2 instance can be launched as a **Dedicated Instance**, which means that the EC2 Host will only be used for instances from one AWS Account. No other AWS customer will be serviced on the same Host as a dedicated instance.

A **Dedicated Host** involves paying for the whole underlying EC2 host and then launching instances on the Host. Again, only one AWS Account can use a dedicated host.

An **Amazon VPC** can be used to create a private, isolated network with control over public/private subnets.

Managed Databases (eg Amazon RDS, Amazon Redshift) can be configured to be **Publicly Accessible**, which means they have a domain name that resolves to a public IP address. If that option is off, they can only be accessed locally.

So, there are lots of options that can make resources "private". How you define "private" is up to you.